# Cropping image form pdf with mupdf

Tags: image, pdf

i'm using mupdf to cropping image from file pdf. but how can i crop with input width, heigh, and possion?
i've tried:

```
mutool convert -O width=100px -O  heigh=100px -o images/image.png demo.pdf 1
mutool draw -O w=100 -O  h=100 -o images/image1.png demo.pdf 1
```

but it's not working :(